# Fitting logistic regression with positive priors

Tags: logistic, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, prior

I'm trying to fit a Logistic regression with positive priors for the coefficients. I tried bayesglm package but the only priors permitted are t-student, normal and Cauchy. For rstanarm, the prior distribution should be one of normal, student_t, cauchy, hs, hs_plus, laplace, lasso, product_normal. Is there any packages or trick that can enforce positive coefficients? For example, allows normal prior for intercept but gamma priors for the rest of the coefficients? I'm trying to avoid JAGS! Thanks.

Comment: I haven't checked the R `rstanarm` or `brms` packages but they use `Stan` which allows one to use truncated normal and $t$ priors.